# The type of column "Date" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to do Pivot and Unpivot on a set of columns:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from tempdb.sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TmpTable')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(a.Date) 
            FROM 
            (Select top 10000 date from 
             #TmpTable
            order by  date) a
            group by a.Date
            order by a.Date
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Date,name,value
                from #TmpTable
                unpivot
                (
                  value for name in ('+@colsUnpivot+')
                ) unpiv
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec(@query)
```

But, I keep getting these errors which I can't figure out why:

> The type of column "Date" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.
>
> Invalid column name 'Date'

The type of `Date` column in the temp table is `datetime`.

Comment: You need to convert it to a string to be compatible with the other columns.

Comment: Without deeping into the issue, I recommend you to use names differents than reserverd words of the database.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting an error with the datatype for the UNPIVOT list for other columns which are in decimal. Should I convert the Value to decimal?

Comment: this is what I have tried but still get the same error: select date,name,CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,4),value) as value
                from #TmpTable

Comment: You have serious problems in naming. reserved names and duplicate names would put you into the trouble

Comment: And finally would you please tell us, what are you going to do? it might be other simple way too